# AppHarbor MassTransit CloudAMQP throws Exception None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Tags: c#, exception, appharbor, masstransit, cloudamqp

I am trying to use Masstransit with CloudAMQP LEMUR from my AppHarbor application, but I am receiving the exception:

*"None of the specified endpoints were reachable"*

This is how Masstransit is configured:

```
Bus.Initialize(sbc =>
                     {
                         sbc.UseRabbitMq();
                         sbc.UseRabbitMqRouting();
                         sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://********-243c-4e49-87fd-ed809c4839f1_apphb.com:EKhooikZAc9SM5t2YW2uc7RGoeFLD7Nv@bunny.cloudamqp.com/7752f6ce-243c-4e49-87fd-ed809c4839f1_apphb.com");
                         sbc.Subscribe(subs => subs.Handler<CreateTweetCommand>((message) => .......................................
```

The versions that I am using are:
MassTransit 2.6.3
MassTransit.RabbitMQ.2.6.3
RabbitMQ.Client.2.8.7
Magnum.2.0.1.0

How can I solve this error?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running this on AppHarbor or on your local machine? I think CloudAMQP might block connections from systems other than AppHarbor.

Comment: The config looks correct, there's some guys on the mailing list that got some cloud stuff working I think. I would try there. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/masstransit-discuss

Comment: CloudAMQP allows connections from 0.0.0.0/0 (anyone).

Comment: Try to add a queue name to the URL: "rabbitmq://user:pass@bunny.cloudamqp.com/vhost/myqueue"

Comment: Also, I recommend you to delete/add your account again as you've published your username and password.

Comment: @friism I am trying it from my local machine before upload to apphb

Comment: @Carl Hörberg I have deleted and created again the account, thanks also for your support by mail. I will try it again and comment how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally It is working, thanks to @Carl Hörberg comments.

I have created a queue and added to my rabbitmq URL, and everything is working fine now.

Thanks guys for the support