# AppHarbor MassTransit CloudAMQP constantly consuming 1,9kB/s

Tags: c#, appharbor, masstransit, consumption, cloudamqp

After making it work:
[AppHarbor MassTransit CloudAMQP throws Exception None of the specified endpoints were reachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089807/appharbor-masstransit-cloudamqp-throws-exception-none-of-the-specified-endpoints)
Now I see in CloudAMQP Management that I have 2 connections constantly consuming 1,9kB/s and 1,4 kB/s which will blow my 30 Mb quickly

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newest MassTransit NuGet should fix this. Chris changed our polling requests so the data usage should be a lot smaller.

https://twitter.com/phatboyg/status/262752508349403136

If it doesn't, reach out to us on the mailing list. Some other people have work arounds I think as well. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/masstransit-discuss

Comment: Great! It works perfectly and now I see in my CloudAMQP Management control panel 0B/s